# window.location.reload() logout from react

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs

I need quick route to logout my user who is stored in localStorage.
I came with this solution but on mobile device is nonstop refreshing
page and not log out as expected. One of my routes is checking if
user is in localStorage and according render component.
I need this logout because I am developing mobile version of page
and can't click on logout link (its momentally because of css overlapping),
which has same logic, so its hard to tell where is problem. So I set up
logout on /logout route. There are 535 ways to reload
js but no way works https://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html

This is my logOut. On Desktop perfecly fine, I think that its because it is in render() method
but not quite sure, can somebody help?

```
const logOut = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('user');
  window.location.reload();
}

<Router>
    <Switch>
       <Route path='/logout' render={()=> {logOut()}}/>
...
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: You need to set the location to a different path than /logout. That’s probably what’s causing the issue. Try window.location = ‘/‘

Answer (score 2):

you immediately run `logOut()` function. that's why you fall in loop.
you should use listeners like onClick. or go to the logout page and logout the user in there for example logout the user in useEffect.

or try this:

```js
const Logout = () => {
    localStorage.clearToken();
    if (localStorage.getItem()) { 
        //check something in local storage so you can know
        // if you should reload or not 

        window.location.reload();
    }
    return 'you were logout';
};
```